# Google Chrome choosing https by default for single site

Tags: google-chrome, http, https

When I type the base domain name into the url bar (example.com) without specifying a protocol, a wireshark capture shows that Chrome is sending its initial SYN packet to 443 for the domain. I'm using a domain redirect that doesn't listen on 443, so it refuses the connection.

If I specify http (http://example.com), everything works as normal. The TCP handshake completes, the HTTP redirect happens, and my browser goes to the intended page.

I have tried clearing cache and deleting any HSTS security policies (there were none), but nothing works.

I sync my chrome across devices, and this behavior is happening on my phone as well.

How do I stop chrome from trying https by default for this one site?

Comment: Update: This just started working, seemingly on its own. I installed an extension called "Link Redirect Trace", and the extension told me to load up a page to capture data, so I tried my problem page, and it just worked. I removed the extension and it still worked. And I completely closed and reopened my browser and it's still working. Don't know why, which is kind of irritating, but at least it works now. Going to leave this question as unanswered in hopes that someone can shed some light on this.